# PowerBI, making wrong calculation

Tags: powerbi

The begining will be very similar the the previous question, but the actual question is something very different...

So, I am trying to create a comparative analysis. I created a measure to calculate the sum of all the entries of different categories and called it Total, and then I used another measure, DRE, to show me either the value of the categorie or the sum of the previous values, if it is a subtotal, this is the DAX formula:

`DRE =  SWITCH( SELECTEDVALUE('Chave de Modelo'[A ou ST]), "A", [Total], "ST", CALCULATE( [Total], FILTER( ALL('Chave de Modelo'), 'Chave de Modelo'[Cont. DRE] < MAX('Chave de Modelo'[Cont. DRE]) ) ) )`

A is not a subtotal an ST is a subtotal.

Problem is, when I put it on my matrix, a Income Statement. All the A values come right, problem is, for soem reason, on a single line with calculation (ST) the Power BI makes the wrong calculation.

If I open the roll and compare using another matrix that shows the details the components are all right, the positives and negatives are there, it was supposed to make give me the right value, but when I look at the actual roll on the matrix the value is completly wrong and I don't even have any idea of how the BI got that value. It is the net revenue, it is not working and I cannot find out why.

Thank you.

I was expecting to have my net revenue calculated on the right way, but soem seemengly random value appeared there out of nowhere. I have literally no idea of why this is happening.

Comment: Try not to reference previous questions in a new question (cut out anything unnecessary to the actual issue. Also there is a ton of spelling mistakes in this question. Try to make it a little clearer